# How to clear an entry () in tkinter from python

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I want to delete the input introduced in the `entry()` pressing a button that is call "Delete input"

I define a function called `SendData()`, and I try to use: `Entryy.clipboard_clear`, and when I test it, it doesn´t do anything.
By the way, this is all of my code:

```
from tkinter import* #importar el tkinter

App = Tk()

def SendData():
    Entryy.clipboard_clear

App.title("HEYYY WASUP")
App.geometry("420x656")
App.config(bg="grey", cursor="cross", relief="sunken", bd="10")    
                                                             
Entryy=Entry()                                                                               
Entryy.grid(row=0, column=2)
Entryy.config(width=25, font=("Comic sans ms", 10))


botonEnviar = Button(text="Delete input")                                               
botonEnviar.grid(row=0, column=5)
botonEnviar.config(font=("Comic sans ms", 10), command= SendData)

App.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is better to specify the parent of widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def SendData():
    Entryy.delete(0, END)
```